# How to get absolute value of a linear expression?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I am currently working on a optimization problem on GUROBI.All my variables are of binary type.I have a variable y which is equal to the absolute of difference of two binary decision variables.However,when i tried to use the abs() function,i get this output.

```
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'gurobipy.LinExpr'
```

Therefore,i am now squaring the difference (since difference is always -1,0 or 1). But this causes higher optimization time(quadratic expressions after squaring). Is there any alternative to this?

Also,there is a case(not binary variables) where the difference of two variables may not be -1,0 or 1.How do i take the absolute in this case?

Answer (score 1):

`y=|x1-x2|` for binary variable is the same as `y = x1 xor x2`. This can be written as:

```
y <= x1+x2 
y >= x1-x2 
y >= x2-x1 
y <= 2-x1-x2
```

(see [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/02/xor-as-linear-inequalities.html)).

When `x1,x2` are continuous variables between 0 and `U` you can write:

```
y1-y2 = x1-x2
y = y1+y2
y1 <= delta*U
y2 <= (1-delta)*U
y1>=0
y2>=0
delta in {0,1}
```

In many cases this can be simplified.

Comment: It there any possibility to rewrite in universally without known `U` / max. value?

Comment: Yes, using SOS1 variables.

Comment: Thanks, SOS1 variables are perfect for it! Short and very fast.